# Why did the DADA teachers before Harry came accept the position?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

By the time Harry came to Hogwarts, the curse on the DADA position had been there for a while, and [these people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76635/who-was-the-dada-teacher-prior-to-harry-s-first-year) had for some reason accepted the job (During the books, they accept the job for [these reasons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/why-did-lockhart-take-the-job)).  Why did the professors accept the job if there had already been a curse for so many years?

Comment: The curse was not widely known—basically only Dumbledore knew about it. Deaths among students or staff also seem to be a pretty damn big deal throughout the books (except during the Battle), and always Harry- or Voldy-related, so there’s nothing to indicate that any of the previous DADA teachers were killed or harmed—quite likely, they just found better jobs, retired, changed to teaching different classes (like Quirrell, but in reverse), only ever meant to teach for a year (like MoodyCrouch), etc. So why _wouldn’t_ they have accepted?

Comment: Because nobody had survived more than a year so far...they had ro suspect.

Comment: There is absolutely no evidence that no one had survived more than a year. Rowling herself has said this in interviews: the curse didn’t involve all the DADA teacher **dying** (Lockhart, Lupin, and Slughorn didn’t die); it only entailed Hogwarts not being able to **keep** DADA teachers more than a year. There are many non-lethal ways of leaving a job, and though some may have noticed how DADA teachers seemed to change all the time, they wouldn’t have any real reason to suspect foul play.

Comment: Besides, not many people outside Hogwarts probably kept that close a tab on who was teaching what when. If you went to apply for (or were approached for) a job teaching at a school, would you assume or require to know who’s had the job for X years before you?

Comment: Survived as in taught more than a year, not literally

Comment: Basically you're asking why somebody would accept a high-turnover job. The answer is: the same reasons people accept any jobs: prestige, interesting work, compensation, benefits, etc... There's always plenty of people running for elected office, even though it's a given that they'll be automatically fired after a few years. Lots of people are eager to get CEO-type jobs, even if the position has a track record of short-duration occupants. Besides, as Janus says, candidates might not have known about the high-turnover situation. Do you know who had your job before you, and how long he was there?

Comment: @Janus: You left out Moody, who also survived his year as DADA teacher (although a bit the worse for wear).

Comment: @PeregrineRook I tend to consider having your soul sucked out of your nostrils as basically being functionally equivalent to death… so yeah… Unless you're talking about the real Moody, who did of course accept, but never actually held the job.

Comment: I was talking about the real Moody.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to have a stab at this, although the answer will be formed of my understanding of opinions.

1) Teaching is rewarding: A normal teaching job sounds awful to many people, but really appealing and rewarding to lots of others.

2) Being a Hogwarts teacher is special: Being a Hogwarts teacher, I am sure (and I know some people question it) would be extra rewarding and feel very special. There is one major British school of magic (and we now know only three or so in all of Europe) and most of its staff have been there a long time and are good at their jobs. It has a thousand year history and basically every British witch or wizard went there. Even Voldemort loved the place! Even Filch stuck around despite being magic-free and surrounded by children who can do things he can't! Vacancies must be rare and those that are interested in a job there would surely have a low chance of getting one except in this job.

3) In some cases, Dumbledore has been persuasive: In the case of Moody and Slughorn, Dumbledore convinced them to join the staff (I know Slughorn joined in a different role but he was against coming back and Dumbledore convinced him). He could have been similarly persuasive to others.

4) Defense Against the Dark Arts is an appealing subject: Each teacher brought something different to the role, and there seems to be a varied curriculum which the teacher has a say in. It is usually practical and involves learning about strange creatures, combat and powerful, mysterious magic. We all know we would enjoy it if we were taught by Lupin or anyone else who knew what they were doing!

5) Accommodation and good food seems to be available as part of the job.

So, in summary, I think it would be a very appealing job in a very appealing establishment even if those that went before didn't stay long.